# Cities XL 2011 resolution error

Tags: technical-issues, cities-xl

Yesterday my brother played Cities XL fine. But now when I run it, my monitor goes to standby, saying "Out of frequency range, set resolution lower".

Other people on the Internet also have this issue. Deleting the "Focus Home Interactive" folder does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows XP

1. Goto

   > %USERPROFILE%\Local
   >   Settings\Application Data\Focus Home
   >   Interactive\Cities XL
   >   2011\live\offline

   OR

   > C:\Documents and Settings{user
   >   name}\Local Settings\Application
   >   Data\Focus Home Interactive\Cities XL
   >   2011\live\offline
2. There is a file `player1.cxl`, delete, move or rename it (Or open in notepad and edit video mode value)
3. Run the game

Answer (score 0):

I renamed `player1.cxl` to `player1.old` and the game started.